# Using HttpGet to get webpage info not working

Tags: android

Hi I am very new to android development and currently work on my first android app project. I want to load web content to the app and stored the content as string. I tried httpGet using AsyncTask but Boolean doInBackground function always returns false. I couldn't find the reason. Could someone help me out? Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public EditText url_text;
    public TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //url_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
        //textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        final String url = "http://www.google.com/";

        new JSONAsyncTask().execute(url);
    }

    public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        public String resultString = "";

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            try {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    resultString = data;



                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Some error occured.");
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            Log.d("TAG", resultString);
        }
    }
}
```

console:
[image: console]

Comment: Is it printing this ` System.out.println("Some error occured.");` ? Check logcat.

Comment: @AJay seems not. It didn't throw exception

Comment: Okay just check if your AndroidManifest.xml file has permission for internet

Comment: yes I added both <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> and 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: I tried you code, and get "result" as true. You might try "breakpoint" to debug.

Comment: Maybe some wrong parameter in the url?!

Comment: Problem solved thank you:)